# Problema ao validar campo 'file'

Tags: javascript

Eu peguei uma function aqui da Internet para tentar validar meu campo 'file', que será para o cliente enviar fotos, quero que o cliente não possa deixar o campo 'file' vazio, sem efetuar upload nenhum, e quero que seja de no máximo 300mb, e que esteja no formato ou 'jpeg' ou 'jpg' ou 'png'.
Eu só consegui um código para validar caso seja maior de 300MB, só não sei se está totalmente certa, essa:

```
function validafoto() {
var upload = document.cad.getElementById("upload");
    var size = upload.files[0].size;
    if(size > 3145728) { //3MB         

      alert('Não permitido'); //Acima do limite
     return false;

}
```

e agora não sei como chamá-la no meu formulário, eu tentei na minha function validarformulario, mas não deu muito certo, poderiam ajudar? Vou deixar o código inteiro do meu formulário aqui: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSFeShPqOtM5dO6_swPcERh52AQyMS3TdMo2fgP_aRvyj4TslepSfQq1I8yUwglb3tvkrJxQ1cwGD1-/pub

Comment: Um jpeg de 300mb? É foto do Hubble? rs

Comment: @dvd `300mb=3MB`, cada `100mb` vale `1MB` capisce

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sabia não rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função está correta na parte de verificar o peso do arquivo, só há um erro neste método: `document.cad.getElementById("upload");`, onde `cad` é o `id` do formulário e não cabe desta forma no método. Teria que ser `document.getElementById("upload");`.

Para saber se o campo está vazio, você pode usar este `if` antes de pegar o `size` do aqruivo:

```
if(!upload.value){
   alert('Selecione um arquivo');
   return false;
}
```

Para verificar o tipo (extensão), seria este `if`:

```
var tipo = upload.value.split(".").pop();          // pego a extensão do arquivo
var valida_tipo = tipo.match(/^(jpeg|jpg|png)$/i); // verifico se é jpeg, jpg ou png
if(!valida_tipo){
   alert('Tipo não permitido');
   return false;
}
```

A função completa ficaria assim:

```
function validafoto() {
   var upload = document.getElementById("upload");
   if(!upload.value){
      alert('Selecione um arquivo');
      return false;
   }

   var tipo = upload.value.split(".").pop();
   var valida_tipo = tipo.match(/^(jpeg|jpg|png)$/i);
   if(!valida_tipo){
      alert('Tipo não permitido');
      return false;
   }

   var size = upload.files[0].size;
   if(size > 3145728) { //3MB         
      alert('Não permitido'); //Acima do limite
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Para validar a partir de outra função, basta chamar `if(!validafoto()) return;`.

Comment: eu coloquei a função no meu código mas continua não funcionando, mesmo sem dar upload no arquivo ele ainda envia o formulário

Comment: Tem que chamar a função da foto na função do formulário. Perai que vou te passar o código.

Comment: posso usar o onchange?

Comment: Na função `validarFormulario()`, inclua a linha `if(!validafoto()) return;`

Comment: O onchange não ficaria bom, tem que validar na função do formulário mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente, @dvd